# ASP.NET MVC Why am I getting System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem for Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a Dropdownlist that displays data from database. The code for my implementation is as follows:

`View`

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Select Your User Type", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Drop")
    </div>
</div>
```

`Controller`

```
ViewBag.Drop = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Name", "Name");
```

I have checked that many online tutorials uses this method. However, whenever I try to save the information, it gives off the error as follows:

[image]

I checked the datatype for the ViewBag.Drop and it was `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` datatype instead of the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem` needed for the `Html.DropDownlist` helper function.

What should I do and how come it changes the type to `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`???

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("Drop", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Are you certain you don't set `ViewBag.Drop` somewhere else?

Comment: show your controller action code.

Comment: Different message because of your terrible use of `DropDownList()`, but same issue - you return the view without re-populating the `SelectList`

Answer (score 1):

You changed the type when you created the list as a SelectList.

What would happen if you did this?:

[ Controller ]

```
var Drop = db.Roles.ToList();
ViewBag.Drop = Drop;
```

[ View ]

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleName, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Drop, "Name", "Name"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Where the Drop declaration creates an IEnumerable List of IdentityRole, and it's passed to the View via the ViewBag. Where (assuming if you're using a ViewModel with a property named RoleName),  you would be selecting the value for the RoleName from the List.

Here you're creating a SelectList and telling it what member of the Drop list to use for the value and what member value to show for selection.